# How to verify sums of subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ U = \{(x, x, y, y) \in \mathbb{R}^4 : x, y \in \mathbb{R} \} $ and $ W = \{(x, x, x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^4 : x, y \in \mathbb{R} \} $.

Then $ U + W = \{(x, x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^4 : x, y, z \in \mathbb{R} \}$

The verification for this (found [here](https://linearalgebras.com/1c.html), Q14), states:

> It is clear that $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Now
> assume that $(x_1,x_1,y_1,y_1) \in U$ and $(x_2,x_2,x_2,y_2) \in W$,
> then:
>
> $ (x_1,x_1,y_1,y_1) + (x_2,x_2,x_2,y_2) = (x_1 + x_2, x_1 + x_2, y_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2) \in \{(x,x,y,z) : x, y,z \in \mathbb{R} \} $
>
> Hence $ U + W \subset \{ (x,x,y,z):x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}\}$.
>
> For any $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $(0,0,y−x,y−x) \in U$ and
> $(x,x,x,z+x−y) \in W$. However, $(x,x,y,z)=(0,0,y−x,y−x)+(x,x,x,z+x−y) \in U+W$, hence $\{(x,x,y,z):x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}\} \subset U+W$.
>
> Combining this with previous argument, it follows that
> $U+W=\{(x,x,y,z):x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Why is the latter part of the argument neccasary to show that the $ U + W = \{(x, x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^4 : x, y, z \in \mathbb{R} \}$? Is the first part of the proof not enough?

Comment: The definition of set $A$ to be equal to set $B$ is that both $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$. So you need to show that both these inclusions hold true.

Comment: @PeldePinda However, after the first part of the proof, we have taken two elements from $U$ and $W$, added them together and shown that the form of the resulting element is that of the elements in the set $U + W$. We haven't just shown that $U+ W$ is a subset, we have shown it is equal by this point?

Comment: Well, no. If $u \in U, w \in W$, then $u + w \in U + W$ by definition. In your proof, you have shown that it is in $\{(x, x, y, z) \ | \ x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}\}$. That does not mean that $U + W = \{(x, x, y, z) \ | \ x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}\}$. What if we take $\mathbb{R}^4$ instead of $\{(x, x, y, z) \ | \ x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first half of the proof is not enough. Consider this variant, where the statement is actually false but the first half of the proof would make it seem true.

**False statement:**
Let $ U = \{(x, x, y, y) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \colon x, y \in \mathbb{R} \} $ and $ W = \{(x, x, x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \colon x, y \in \mathbb{R} \} $. Then $ U + W = \{(w, x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \colon w, x, y, z \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

**Erroneous proof:**
It is clear that $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Now
assume that $(x_1,x_1,y_1,y_1) \in U$ and $(x_2,x_2,x_2,y_2) \in W$;
then
$$
(x_1,x_1,y_1,y_1) + (x_2,x_2,x_2,y_2) = (x_1 + x_2, x_1 + x_2, y_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2) \in \{(x,x,y,z) \colon w, x, y,z \in \mathbb{R} \}.
$$
Hence $ U + W = \{ (w,x,y,z):x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

(This is a correct proof that $ U + W \subset \{ (w,x,y,z):x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}\}$, but it does not prove—and it's not true—that $ U + W = \{ (w,x,y,z):x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}\}$.)